# I want to run jvm on arduino.What minimum configuration do I need?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, electronics, java

If Arduino IDE itself is built on Java can I run JVM on the Arduino? If yes how should I do it?

Comment: An Arduino is the wrong choice for this task.

Comment: Ah, why do you want to do this?

Comment: Which limited memory hardware I can use here? I want to use in robotics and want to run machine on java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "embedded java". Oracle supports it for ARM cores, which is what some of the arduino-like boards such as the Teensy 3.X have, but I doubt they have enough resources to support it.

There is haiku-vm (google it!) that's designed with AVR processors in mind, but I don't know how actively it is being worked on.

Googling "embedded java avr" yields a tremendous amount of results; did you even try that?

Comment: Thank you very much for suggestions. I've tried searching vms. They support limited java libraries though. I want to know some other options if any.Also I don't know what hardware resources are required to support jvm.I went through nano vm too.Your suggestions helped me.